# Samba file server as domain member: error when joining domain

Tags: active-directory, samba, kerberos, samba4, winbind

I would like to set up samba 4 to share a local directory, so that domain users are allowed to mount the directory. I don't want domain users to be able to log in the linux machine, they should only be able to use the shared directory.

There are 3 machines involved:

1. **dc**: A windows server 2012 acting as domain controller.
2. **workstation**: A windows workstation, that is actually the same machine than dc but this is only because i don't have 2 windows and
   should not matter.
3. **samba**: A linux server with a directory (/srv/rw) that should be shared on the network

I want that, when a domain user is logged in on "workstation", he can see the share on "samba", without being prompted for login/password. I followed this tutorial: http://linuxtot.com/add-a-simple-samba-file-server-as-a-domain-member/

When i try to join "samba" (the machine) to the domain, i get an error:

```
root@samba:~# net ads join -S rootdomainname.com -U "Administrator%password"
kinit succeeded but ads_sasl_spnego_krb5_bind failed: Server not found in Kerberos database
Failed to join domain: failed to connect to AD: Server not found in Kerberos database
```

I can see on the network an error with kerberos during the `net ads join` command:
[image: KRB5KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN]

What does "Kerberos database" refers to ? Is that the one in the AD ?

Also, i don't have any file "/etc/krb5.conf" on my linux machine, is that normal ? Some tutorials refer to this file.

Any idea what the problem is ?

Comment: why the downvote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of nowhere it suddenly worked:
do NOT specify `-S rootdomainname.com` in net ads

Comment: Emm.... AFAIK `-S` is the "server" key to point to specific DC, not to domain itself?